# get :index Rspec error, during unit test for Static Index controller page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I'm currently attempting my first unit test and I'm receiving the following errors

Failures:

1) StaticPagesController GET #index responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code
     Failure/Error: get :index

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
 # /Users/danielmayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:112:in `authenticate_user!'
 # ./spec/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

2) StaticPagesController GET #index renders the index template
     Failure/Error: get :index

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `authenticate!' for nil:NilClass
 # /Users/danielmayle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:112:in `authenticate_user!'
 # ./spec/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe StaticPagesController, :type => :controller do
  context "GET #index" do
    before do
      get :index
    end

    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it "renders the index template" do
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end

end
```

And here is my static_controller.rb code:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
 def index
 end

def landing_page
    @featured_product = Product.first
end

  def thank_you
    @name = params[:name]
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = params[:message]
    UserMailer.contact_form(@email, @name, @message).deliver_now
  end

end
```

Why do are these errors coming up and how do I fix the problem? I've only been coding for a few months so any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Update

Here is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?


  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_url, :alert => exception.message

  end

  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

Here is my user_mailer code as well

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "dmayle012@gmail.com"

    def contact_form(email, name, message)
        @message = message
        mail(:from => email,
            :to => 'dmayle012@gmail.com',
            :subject => "New ActionMail Message from #{name}")
    end
end
```

Comment: Please show your application controller. Your error is caused as your `current_user` is nil.

Comment: Application controller code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

This makes devise to check authorisation for `current_user`, which is nil in your test. There are two ways to fix it depending on what your requirements are.

Firstly, if you want any internet user to be able to view your static pages without login, add:

```
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
```

in your StaticPagesController. This will tell devise that you don't require current_user to be allowed to view the page (not really - it doesn't tell devise anything, it just not asking it to authorise user).

Second option - you need user to be logged in to view those pages. In this case you need to create fake session before you start your test using some helper methods provided by devise. This is very easy and well documented process, you can find the steps here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)#controller-specs. Not adding those steps in the answer as I believe you will go with first case (since every page requires some pages available without the session, at least for the login page).

Comment: Awesome thanks the first option fixed the problem. Thanks for the assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Devise has some helper methods specifically for this. Here is how to setup your controller spec to get past your `undefined method authenticate_user! for nil` error

First you need to include them in your rails_helper.rb like this

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

And then you can use the helper like this in your static pages controller

```
# spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb
describe StaticPagesController, :type => :controller do
  context "GET #index" do
    before :each do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, approved: true)
      sign_in :user, user
      get :index
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the information that was actually the next part of my lesson, so you explaining it further really helps.

Comment: Click the check mark next to this answer and the up arrow